# C# to Excel, find last row used

Tags: c#

Below is my C# code to send dynamically created textboxes to Excel. I need to find the last row used for these textboxes so I can start my next for loop 6 rows below the first set.

```
int StartBundleRow = 11;
for (int BndlRow = 0; BndlRow < bundleRows; BndlRow++) //add bundle rows to spreadsheet
{
    worksheet.Rows[StartBundleRow].Insert();
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "D"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtQtyBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "E"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProductNameBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "F"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtListPriceBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "G"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtMaxDiscountBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow++, "H"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProposedPriceBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
}
```

Comment: Use a var such as "int _lastRowWritten" and update it as you go.

Comment: I understand how to create the "int" but I am unsure about updating it ;)...Excel automation is quite new to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like this every time you need to run your sequence:

```
int numRows = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

sheet is of the type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet`

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Of course this only works if s/he is populating a new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const int ROW_CUSHION = 6;
int StartBundleRow = 11;
int nextStartingRow = StartBundleRow;
for (int BndlRow = 0; BndlRow < bundleRows; BndlRow++) //add bundle rows to spreadsheet
{
    worksheet.Rows[StartBundleRow].Insert();
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "D"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtQtyBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "E"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProductNameBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "F"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtListPriceBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow, "G"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtMaxDiscountBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
    worksheet.Cells[StartBundleRow++, "H"].value = srcBundlePanel.Controls["txtProposedPriceBundle" + BndlRow].Text;
}
nextStartingRow = nextStartingRow + ROW_CUSHION;
```

For example, here's an excerpt from some of my, similar, code:

```
const int TIMES_BEFORE_ITS_CHARMING = 3;
private int _lastRowAdded;
. . .
_lastRowAdded = _curDescriptionTopRow + TIMES_BEFORE_ITS_CHARMING;
. . .
var descriptionColRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[DATA_STARTING_ROW, ITEMDESC_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[_lastRowAdded, ITEMDESC_COL]];
```

So I assign to it based on another value + a "cushion" value (3 above); it can be updated throughout the code, as needed. Then I use the value for things like describing a Range of cells on which to operate.

Comment: Well, it doesn't completely not work, lol. It puts both loops together basically but it doesnt skip and start 6 rows lower. I can probably adjust it.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tel exactly what you need without seeing more of your code, but I'm successfully doing something very similar with my Interop utility.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I declare Row_cushion an integer instead of a constant ? When I try to make it a constant it says I'm missing a reference or "using". That is the only difference I have

Comment: Thank you for steering me in the direction!!

Comment: OOOOh wait, I just caught what we are doing..with this it is telling the next group to start on 17 basically. I already tried that one, the only problem is, when I create the dynamics it may be more or less each time so starting at an actual number will not work.

Comment: my next for loop is exactly the same as the above code but I cant tell it to start at 17 because of what I mentioned. The template I am using has some headings, text ,etc... under the first group, thats why I need to skip 6 rows after the first group.

Comment: It should only be 17 the first time; the next time you update the value, it will be whatever it was before + whatever "cushion" you need to add.

Comment: Everything is good now, thanks for your help. I ended up going with this : int StartAddOn = StartBundleRow + bundleRows + 6; this grabs the last used row and adds 6 to it.